# Quicksort and Bubblesort with pointers, implement both of these into calc.c

Tags: c, pointers, quicksort

I am trying to figure out how to first modify my quicksort program to use pointer arithmetics, then change my bubblesort program to a recursive program that uses pointers and finally implement both of these programs into a calculator (calc.c) program. I will post the codes I have in the order that they were mentioned.

Quicksort:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10
void quicksort(int a[], int low, int high);
int split(int a[], int low, int high);
int main(void)
{
    int a[N], i;
    printf("Enter %d numbers to be sorted: ", N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    quicksort(a, 0, N - 1);
    // bubblesort(a, 0, N-1);
    printf("In sorted order: ");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void quicksort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int middle;
    if (low >= high) return;
    middle = split(a, low, high);
    quicksort(a, low, middle - 1);
    quicksort(a, middle + 1, high);
}

int split(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int part_element = a[low];
    for (;;) {
        while (low < high && part_element <= a[high])
            high--;
        if (low >= high) break;
        a[low++] = a[high];
        while (low < high && a[low] <= part_element)
            low++;
        if (low >= high) break;
        a[high--] = a[low];
    }
    a[high] = part_element;
    return high;
}
```

Bubblesort:

```
void bubblesort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    for (j = high; j > low; j--) {
        for (i = low+1; i <= j;i++) {
            if (a[i] < a[i-1]) {
                temp=a[i];a[i]=a[i-1];a[i-1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calc.c:

```
/**  To compile this code, use                         **
 *  gcc -o calc calc.c -std=c99 -lm                    **/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define KEY "Enter the calculator operation you want to do: "
#define enter_option() printf("%s", KEY)

#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 15
#define clear_screen() \
for ( int i = 0; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT; i++ ) printf("\n");

#define clean_input() while ((getchar())!='\n') continue;

#define calculator_operations() printf("\n"); \
printf("********    Welcome to C calculator     ***********\n"); \
printf("**-----------------------------------------------**\n"); \
printf("**   Press 'Q' or 'q' to quit the program        **\n"); \
printf("**   Press 'H' or 'h' to display below options   **\n"); \
printf("**   Press 'C' or 'c' to clear the screen        **\n"); \
printf("**-----------------------------------------------**\n"); \
printf("**   Enter 'A' or 'a' for arithmetic mode        **\n"); \
printf("**   Enter 'F' or 'f' for function mode          **\n"); \
printf("**   Enter 'S' or 's' for sorting mode           **\n"); \
printf("***************************************************\n"); \
printf("\n");

#define DISP(f,x) printf(#f"(%g) = %g\n",x,f(x));
#define DISP_I(f,x) printf(#f"(%d) = %d\n",(int) x,(int) f((int) x));

// Function prototype declaration
void arith_mode();
void func_mode();
void sort_mode();
void read_line(char *);
int factorial(int );

// Start of Main Program
int main()
{
    int X=1;
    char Calc_Mode;

    do
    {
        calculator_operations();
        enter_option();
        Calc_Mode=getchar();

        switch(Calc_Mode)
        {
            case 'A': case 'a': arith_mode(); break;
            case 'F': case 'f': func_mode(); break;
            case 'S': case 's': sort_mode(); break;
                // Can you integrate the quick sort program into our calculator?

            case 'H': case 'h': case '\n': break;

            case 'Q': case 'q': printf("Leaving Calculator!\n");
                exit(0);

            case 'C': case 'c': clear_screen();
                clean_input(); break;
        }

    } while (X);
}

//Function Definitions

void arith_mode()
{
    double value, operand;
    char operator;

    printf("\nPlease enter arithmetic expression "
           "as in \"x +-*/%%^ y +-*/%%^ z ...\" \n");
    printf("Your expression is: ");

    /* Read first operand */
    scanf("%lf", &value);

    /* Read successive operators and operands */
    while ((operator = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (operator == ' ') continue;

        scanf("%lf", &operand);
        switch (operator) {
            case '+': value += operand; break;
            case '-': value -= operand; break;
            case '*': value *= operand; break;
            case '/': value /= operand; break;
            case '%': value = ((int) value)%((int) operand); break;
            case '^': value = pow(value,operand); break;
            default:  printf("\n Invalid Operator! \n"); exit(0);
        }
    }

    /* Print result */
    printf("Value of expression: %g\n\n", value);
}

void func_mode()
{
    char *cp, func_initial, line[40];
    double variable;

    printf("\nPlease enter functions as in "
           "\"name(x)\". \n");
    printf("Your function is: ");

    clean_input();

    read_line(line);
    func_initial = line[0];

    for (cp = line; *cp; cp++) {
        if (*cp == '(') {
            sscanf(++cp,"%lf", &variable);
            switch (func_initial) {
                case 'F': case 'f': DISP_I(factorial,variable); break;
                case 'E': case 'e': DISP(exp,variable); break;
                case 'S': case 's': DISP(sqrt,variable); break;
                default: printf("\n Invalid Function! \n"); exit(0);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

void sort_mode()
{
    clean_input();
    printf("\nComing Attraction!!!\n");
    printf("We'll integrate the quicksort program into our calculator!!!\n\n");
}

void read_line(char *line)
{
    int index; char ch;

    index = 0;
    while ((ch= getchar()) !='\n') {
        if (ch == ' ') continue;
        line[index++] = ch;
    }

    line[index] = '\0';
}

int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n<=1) return 1;
    else return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

Comment: What is your question? All I see is a code dump.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to first modify my quicksort program to use pointer arithmetics, then change my bubblesort program to a recursive program that uses pointers and finally implement both of these programs into a calculator (calc.c) program

Comment: I need to know how to do that because I have absolutely no idea how

Comment: Those aren't really specific questions. There are more requests to re-write your code. For example "modify my quicksort program to use pointer arithmetic". That is not a well defined question. It could mean many things or mean nothing. Which part of the code do you think needs to use pointer arithmetic and why do you think pointer arithmetic is appropriate? Bottom line - on SO you need to ask specific questions rather than "re-write my code" type questions.

Comment: I'd start by reviewing whatever class notes, text, tutorial, or combinations therein that cover [pointer arithmetic](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html). I'd also review the [bubblesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) algorithm before attempting to write a recursive one. What you have *now* isn't full-on bubblesort The correct algorithm includes swap detection; it is the attribute that gives bubblesort best-case O(n), and your's seems to be lacking it. It would be a shame to implement the wrong algorithm *twice*.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer based quick sort's header should look like this:

```
void quicksort(int * low, int * high)
{
int * middle = low + ((high-low)/2);
/* ... */
```